# How to generate a URL for ASP.NET MVC action, including hostname and port?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

My current request is:

> http://www.mofeng.com:4355/

I want display an action url in asp.net view layer, url is like this(full url, including *http://protocol* + *hostname* + *port* + *controllerName* + *actionName*):

> http://www.mofeng.com:4355/controllerX/actionY

Comment: try urlhelper `url.Action("ViewAction", "MyModelController", new { id = this.ID });`

Comment: If your routing match the default route first (without the controller and action value) you should exclude the default parameters on the routing or create a new routing for this scenario before the defaults.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[image]

```
Url.Action("Action", "Controller", null, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

### **How to include the following in the Form Action attribute?**

> **1. Protocol(http:// or https://)**
>   **2. HostName**
>  
>   **3. QueryString**
>  
>   **4. Port**

```
@{
    var actionURL = Url.Action("Action", "Controller", 
                               FormMethod.Post, Request.Url.Scheme)  
                    + Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, 
                                                   new { @action = actionURL }))
{
}
```

Comment: the Html.BeginForm() has the override method that can hold the 4 items above such as protocol, hostname etc. anyway it works fine, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

besides the default route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Application", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

you may need to implement a new one :

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ControllerXActionYRoute",
            url: "controllerX/actionY",
            defaults: new { controller = "controllerX", action = "actionY" }
        );
```

and then you can use :

```
<div>@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", null, Request.Url.Scheme);</div>
```

**EDIT: **

to get the full url you must go to absolute.

```
<div>VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(@Url.Action("Action", "Controller"));</div>
```

Comment: this is really i should do. it seems that the port can not be got into url in this way?!

Comment: different port means you want to link to **another** application. In that case, how the app will know how to match the action and controller to an appropiate route ? There's no use of the Url.Action for using a different port than running **the same** application in http or https

Comment: nevermind, updated the answer to show you how to get the absolute url.

Comment: ok, after deployment, the site will hidden the port right? thank you Bart

Comment: yes paul. If site is on default web port (80) won't be shown.