# Request.Url.Scheme not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net MVC. My code is:

```
var url = Url.Action(
                   "ConfirmEmail", "Account",
                   new { userId = id, code = code },
                   protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```

On localhost it is returning right url i.e,

`https://localhost:44300/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=bed34d05-2b7b-49b8-940e-0d89d4870d17&code=AQAA`

But on live website its not working as expected. The url it returns is:

`http://newtemp.apphb.com:16169/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=7ba65316-0901-4c27-9371-588a5e945baa&code=AQAA`

the portion `:16169` is addational. Where it came from and how to remove this?

My detailed code is:

```
public async Task<bool> SendMailtoConfirmEmailAddress(string id,string name,string email)
        {
            var user = await db.AspNetUsers.FindAsync(id);
            if (user.EmailConfirmed)
            {
                return false;
            }
            try
            {
                var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("http://newtemp.apphb.com/");
                UserManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, string>(provider.Create("UserToken"))
                    as IUserTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, string>;

                var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action(
                   "ConfirmEmail", "Account",
                   new { userId = id, code = code },
                   protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

                ElectronicsController.sendEmail(email, "Welcome to dealkar.pk - Confirm Email address", "Hello " + name + "!<br/>Confirm your email address by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a> OR " + callbackUrl);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string s = e.ToString();
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: maybe `Request.Url.Host` is what you are looking for?

Comment: nope. on localhost it returns `localhost://localhost/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=abc&code=def`

Comment: It comes from Request.Url.Scheme .Have a look at this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552760/how-to-generate-a-url-for-asp-net-mvc-action-including-hostname-and-port

Comment: and how to remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where it came from?

The [port is resolved from the current request](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/UrlHelper.cs#L162-L165). Unfortunately, Microsoft didn't account for when a URL is generated on a server that is running a non-default port and it will just use the current one (whether or not the protocol is the same as the current request).

> how to remove this?

You can create an extension method to tell the `UrlHelper` to use the default port regardless of the port of the incoming request.

This example creates a fake HTTP Context based on the default port (80 for HTTP, 443 for HTTPS), then uses a new instance of `UrlHelper` to resolve the URL.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string Action(this UrlHelper helper, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, string protocol, bool defaultPort)
    {
        return Action(helper, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, protocol, null, defaultPort);
    }

    public static string Action(this UrlHelper helper, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, string protocol, string hostName, bool defaultPort)
    {
        if (!defaultPort)
        {
            return helper.Action(actionName, controllerName, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), protocol, hostName);
        }

        string port = "80";
        if (protocol.Equals("https", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            port = "443";
        }

        Uri requestUrl = helper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;
        string defaultPortRequestUrl = Regex.Replace(requestUrl.ToString(), @"(?<=:)\d+?(?=/)", port);
        Uri url = new Uri(new Uri(defaultPortRequestUrl, UriKind.Absolute), requestUrl.PathAndQuery);

        var requestContext = GetRequestContext(url);
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(requestContext, helper.RouteCollection);

        var values = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);
        values.Add("controller", controllerName);
        values.Add("action", actionName);

        return urlHelper.RouteUrl(null, values, protocol, hostName);
    }

    private static RequestContext GetRequestContext(Uri uri)
    {
        // Create a TextWriter with null stream as a backing stream 
        // which doesn't consume resources
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(Stream.Null))
        {
            var request = new HttpRequest(
                filename: string.Empty,
                url: uri.ToString(),
                queryString: string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri.Query) ? string.Empty : uri.Query.Substring(1));
            var response = new HttpResponse(writer);
            var httpContext = new HttpContext(request, response);
            var httpContextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext);
            return new RequestContext(httpContextBase, new RouteData());
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
        var url = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account",
               new { userId = 123, code = 456 },
               protocol: Request.Url.Scheme,
               defaultPort: true);
```